# Adapt elements in the list, condition by condition

Tags: conditional

Could you give me some advice?

Suppose I have the following list.

```
box[1,1]={{4.4, {1,1}, {a}}, {1.5, {1,1}, {a}}, {10.8, {2,1}, {3a}}, {10, {1, 3}, {3a}}}
```

I want to do the following.

When the location of Part[box[1, 1][[x]], 3] is {a}, apply it to the contents of the brackets as a=1.

When the location is not {a} (here are {3a} and{4a}), apply it to the contents of the brackets as a=0.1.

So,I want to construct formula that yields the following answer.

```
box[1,1]={{4.4, {1, 1}, {1}}, {1.5, {1, 1}, {1}}, {10.8, {5, 2}, {0.3}}, {10, {1, 3}, {0.3}}, {10, {1, 3}, {0.4}}}
```

I tryed to used "If" and "MenberQ".
At that time,  it was all calculated as a=1 or a=0.1. I felt like MenberQ is not distinct "a" and x"a". What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

```
box[1, 1] = 
  {{4.4, {1, 1}, {a}}, 
   {1.5, {1, 1}, {a}},
   {10.8, {2, 1}, {3 a}},
   {10, {1, 3}, {4 a}}};

box[1, 1] /. {{a} -> {1}, a -> .1}
```

> ```
>  {{4.4, {1, 1}, {1}}, 
>   {1.5, {1, 1}, {1}},
>   {10.8, {2, 1}, {0.3}},
>   {10, {1, 3}, {0.4}}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
box[1, 1] /. {x_ a :> .1 x, a -> 1}

box[1, 1] /. x_. a :> If[x == 1, 1, .1 x]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That will help immensely.

Comment: @hare, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.